# coq. ordered pair of natual numbers

Tags: coq

I am trying to defined an inductive data type to hold pair of natural numbers. Here is what I have done

```
   Definition ordered_pair := (nat * nat) % type.

   Inductive nat_pair(A B:nat):ordered_pair:=
     |pair :ordered_pair->ordered_pair.
```

It generates exception

```
   Anomaly: Uncaught exception Reduction.NotArity. Please report.
```

Does anyone know there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inductive definition just does not make sense.

The type `ordered_pair` you have defined is already a type for pairs of natural numbers.
It is defined as the pair type, applied to arguments of type `nat`, so to build such a pair you could do:

```
Definition p : ordered_pair := (23, 42).
```

Now if you wanted to define a "similar" (but not "identical") type inductively, the syntax would be:

```
Inductive nat_pair : Set :=
| pair : nat -> nat -> nat_pair
.
```

Notice that you don't take natural numbers as parameters in the type, but rather the constructor contains two such numbers.

You seem to have some misunderstanding of inductive definitions, so I'd suggest reading more about them.

Comment: he exception you face is because the arity (read "type" if you are not familiar with the notion of arity) of an inductive type has to be of the shape `forall (x_1: A_1) (x_2: A_2) ... (x_n: A_n), Prop`, `forall (x_1: A_1) (x_2: A_2) ... (x_n: A_n), Set` or `forall (x_1: A_1) (x_2: A_2) ... (x_n: A_n), Type`. This is the full form, usually it is non-dependent and just of the shape `A_1 -> ... -> A_n -> Prop` (and so on). In you case, it was of arity `nat -> nat -> ordered_pair` which is not allowed.

Comment: Yeah, newer versions of Coq have a slightly less cryptic error message, but it's still about arity which might be confusing to the beginner. The basic idea is that the types you may enrich with  inductive definitions are `Set` `Prop` and `Type`, and never user-defined types like `ordered_pair`. But even that seems like a complex explanation for someone who seems confused about inductive type definitions themselves.